# Meaning of "take by mouth" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It’s recommended that you take zinc **by mouth**.

It is from this [article](https://www.healthline.com/health/cold-flu/common-cold-treatments-make-you-sick). What I think the author means by that is taking zink orally, but Although I am not a native, the use of *by mouth* feels akward to me. Perhaps it had a different meaning I am not aware of.

Comment: They went by foot and played it by ear. They like to do things by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct:

> orally adverb (by mouth)

[dictionary.cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/orally)

> - BY MOUTH (adverb)
>     The adverb **BY MOUTH** has 1 sense:
>
>   1. (of drugs) through the mouth rather than through injection
>
>   Familiarity information: **BY MOUTH** used as an adverb is very rare.

[https://www.audioenglish.org](https://www.audioenglish.org/dictionary/by_mouth.htm)

Comment: If you are going to have a general anaesthetic in a British hospital, and you must not eat or drink anything, a notice proclaiming "Nil by mouth" will be attached to your bed, and you may be asked to wear a bracelet with those words on it.

Comment: In the US you might also see NPO (for *nil | nihil | nulla per os*).